# Cancel a DeferWindowPos

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I am doing a series of window resizing using the DeferWindowPos functionality.   Suppose I already opened the DeferWindowPos handle, and called DeferWindowPos a few time, and now I want to cancel everything: not call EndDeferWindowPos.  I tried CloseHandle( hDWP ), but it does not work (crash).  If I simply return from my function, I assume it will leak an handle.  It is possible to terminate the DeferWindowPos without calling EndDeferWindowPos?

```
// Initialize
HDWP hDWP = BeginDeferWindowPos( ... )

for( ... )
{  
   // Calculate new rectangle
   CRect dcNew;
   ...
   // Oh,now I want to return from my function, I want to cancel everything

   // Accumulate
   hDWP = DeferWindowPos( hDWP, hWnd, 0, 
                rcNew.left, 
                rcNew.top, 
                rcNew.Width(), 
                rcNew.Height(),
                SWP_NOZORDER );
}

// Finally
BOOL bResult = EndDeferWindowPos( hDWP );
```

If this is not possible, I will simply accumulate them in a temporary vector, and call the Defer stuff at the end, when I am certain I want to do them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reference to any kind of "abort" functionality I see is this:

> If any of the windows in the
>   multiple-window- position structure
>   have the SWP_HIDEWINDOW or
>   SWP_SHOWWINDOW flag set, none of the
>   windows are repositioned.

This is coming from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632672(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: They wouldn't be repositioned, but they would still be hidden/shown right? To my knowledge you simply can't show/hide, and reposition within the same call.

Answer (score 0):

*"If this is not possible, I will simply accumulate them in a temporary vector, and call the Defer stuff at the end, when I am certain I want to do them all."*

**This would be the right solution.** What is your argument for being indecisive about which windows to reposition in between `BeginDeferWindowPos`, `DeferWindowPos` and `EndDeferWindowPos`? This seems to relate more to a threading issue which you can solve using appropriate locking.

[Arkadiy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/495486/590790)'s answer does not 'cancel' anything. As far as I understand the [Win32 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632672(v=vs.85).aspx), *you simply can't combine show/hide operations, with repositioning operations*. In other words, **you do not cancel the operation**, the show/hide operations simply take precedence and those are the ones which will be executed.

I encapsulated showing/hiding and repositioning in a managed library: [Framework Class Library Extension](https://github.com/Whathecode/Framework-Class-Library-Extension).

The specific `RepositionWindows()` function is located in [Whathecode.System.Windows.WindowManager](https://github.com/Whathecode/Framework-Class-Library-Extension/blob/master/Whathecode.System/Windows/WindowManager.cs) and it takes care of both showing/hiding and repositioning.

```
/// <summary>
///   Reposition a set of windows in one operation.
///   TODO: Handle any scenarios where repositioning windows fails.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="toPosition">The windows to reposition.</param>
/// <param name="changeZOrder">
///   When true, the windows's Z orders are changed to reflect the order of the toPosition list.
///   The first item in the list will appear at the top, while the last item will appear at the bottom.
/// </param>
public static void RepositionWindows( List<RepositionWindowInfo> toPosition, bool changeZOrder = false )
{
    bool changeVisibility = toPosition.Any( w => w.HasVisibilityChanged() );
    if ( changeVisibility )
    {
        RepositionWindows( toPosition, false, true );
    }
    RepositionWindows( toPosition, changeZOrder, false );
}
```